# timedatectl изменение времени без часового пояса

Tags: linux, bash

timedatectl

надо сделать скрипт, который будет изменять только часы, без изменения часового пояса и полного прописывания времени

то есть, запускается скрипт и время просто изменяется согласно прописанному в скрипте часовому поясу или указания определенного части времени , только часов или минут

Answer (score 0):

В любом случае время переписывается полностью. Поэтому читай текущее и сразу изменяй.

Можно командой `date` для установки времени по формату, например, для установки часа:

```
sudo date +"%H" -s 13
```

Временная зона и так ставится отдельно.